# Can protractor get ERROR and FATAL messages from browser logs?

Tags: javascript, logging, browser, protractor, error-logging

Is it possible for protractor to find ERROR and FATAL messages reported by application under test?

I use browser.manage().logs().get('browser')... to tests the length of the returned array and fail the test if array size is > 0.

It works well until I set browser to 'ERROR' in loggingPrefs.

I see that the logging levels available in protractor are: “OFF”, “SEVERE”, “WARNING”, “INFO”, “CONFIG”, “FINE”, “FINER”, “FINEST”, “ALL”.

I wonder what is the way to get to other level messages (ERROR/FATAL) which might appear in the browser when application throws them.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably just want `SEVERE` and `WARNING`.  Or, you can do `ALL` and just use `filter()` to find ERROR and FATAL

Comment: Thank you Gunderson. I definitely need ERROR and FATAL but the question is whether I will get them if I use ALL or these levels are not being harvested at all if all that is being caught is the levels mentioned above? Thanks again!